# How do I find the Collection Membership Information with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, collections, sccm, computer-name

I have the following code, but I get an "Invalid Namespace" error constantly, I am pretty sure I am entering the correct information.

If you have another way of doing this, it's also accepted.

```
Param(
    $SiteCode,
    $SourceFile,
    $Destination = "$env:USERPROFILE\DESKTOP\Computers.csv"
)


$Computers = Get-Content $SourceFile
$EmptyArray = @()

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    $ResourceIDQuery = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\sms\site_$SiteCode" -Class SMS_R_SYSTEM -Filter "Name='$computer'"

    $CollectionQuery = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\sms\site_$SiteCode" -Class SMS_CollectionMember_a -filter "ResourceID='$($ResourceIDQuery.ResourceId)'"

    foreach($Item in $CollectionQuery)
    {
        $DObject = New-Object PSObject
            $Dobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer" -Value $computer 
            $Dobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ResID" -Value $($ResourceIDQuery.ResourceId)
            $Dobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "CollID" -Value $($Item.CollectionId)
            $Dobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DirectOrNot" -Value $($Item.IsDirect)
        $EmptyArray += $Dobject
    }
}

$EmptyArray | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $Destination
```

Comment: Run `Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\sms" -Class "__NAMESPACE" | Format-List name` to check whether your SMS sites exist.

Comment: @davor I just get "invalid namespace" again.

Comment: I get "invalid namespace" too. That is because SMS is not installed on my client...

Comment: it's actually `root\cimv2\sms` now, just a heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than connecting to each computer and extracting the information (slow) get it from the straight from the database....

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ( 
        [string] $hosts = "",
        [string] $sccmsrv = "",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=3)]
        [string] $path = ""
    )

$usage =  "USAGE: List-AdvertCollMembershipSCCM.ps1 -sccmsrv SCCMSERVER -hosts 'host1 host2 host3' -path 'c:\temp\Outfile.csv'"

if ($host -and $sccmsrv){

Write-Host ""       
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "SCCM Server: $sccmsrv"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Looking at hosts: $hosts"


  #### Function for executing a SQL query with integrated authentication  
  function execSQLQuery ([string]$fSQLServer, [string]$db, [string]$query){  
    $objConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection  
    $objConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $fSQLServer; Database = $db; trusted_connection=true;"  
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $query, $objConnection  
    trap {Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'red' "($sqlsrv/$db not accessible)";continue}   
    $SqlCmd.Connection.Open()  

    if ($SqlCmd.Connection.State -ine 'Open') {  
       $SqlCmd.Connection.Close()  
       return  
    }  
    $dr = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()  

    #get the data  
    $dt = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"  
    $dt.Load($dr)  
    $SqlCmd.Connection.Close()  
    $dr.Close()  
    $dr.Dispose()  
    $objConnection.Close()  
    return $dt  
  }  

  # read the SCCM site name of the SCCM site server  
  $site = (gwmi -ComputerName $sccmsrv -Namespace root\sms -Class SMS_ProviderLocation).sitecode  

  # enumerating SQL server name for the given SCCM site server  
  $sccmCompquery = gwmi -q "Select distinct SiteSystem, Role, SiteCode FROM SMS_SiteSystemSummarizer where role = 'SMS SQL Server' and siteCode = '$site' ORDER BY SiteCode" -namespace "root\sms\site_$site" -ComputerName $sccmsrv  
  [string]$tmpstr = [regex]::Match($sccmCompquery.sitesystem, "\\\\\w+\\$")  
  $sccmSQLServer = $tmpstr.replace("\", "")  
  $objColl = @()  

  #### Collate the host list.  
  $hostlist = @($Input)  
  if ($hosts) {  
    if($hosts -imatch " "){  
       $hostsArr = @($hosts.split(" "))
       $hostlist += $hostsArr  
    }  
    else{  
       $hostlist += $hosts  
    }  
  }  

  # going through the list of hosts  
  foreach($srv in $hostlist){  
    $memberQuery = "SELECT dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.Name AS 'Hostname', dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID, dbo.v_Collection.Name AS 'Collection Name', dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID, dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.IsDirect "  
    $memberQuery += "FROM dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership INNER JOIN dbo.v_Collection ON dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM ON dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID "  
    $memberQuery += "WHERE (LOWER(dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.Name) = LOWER('$srv'))"  

    # running sql query to enumerate list of collections the computer is member of  
    $membership = execSQLQuery $sccmSQLServer "SMS_$site" $memberQuery  

    # if we have a result, go through it and build an object collection with the computer name and the collection(s) it is member of  
    if($membership){  
       foreach($enumColl in $membership){

        $sObject = $enumColl | select Hostname, ResourceID, "Collection Name", CollectionID, IsDirect
        $objColl +=$sObject

       }  
    }  
  }


if ($objColl){
    if ($path){
        $objColl | ft -AutoSize
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Exporting to results to: $path"
        $objColl | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
    }
    else{
    $objColl | ft -AutoSize
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Use the -path argument in the command line to export output to csv to display"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "the 'IsDirect' Information"
    Write-Host ""
    }
}
Else {
    foreach ($Hostname in $hostlist){
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The host $hostname is not a member of any collection"
    }
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Check you have entered the correct hostname and try again"
}
}
else {

    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $usage
}
```

Execution:-

```
PS C:\> ListSCCMCollections.ps1 -sccmsrv SCCMSERVER -hosts host1,host2,host3 -path "c:\temp\Outfile.csv"
```

or

```
PS C:\> Get-Content hostlist.txt | ListSCCMCollections.ps1 -sccmsrv SCCMSERVER -path c:\temp\Outfile.csv
```

Getting the requested info straight from SQL:-

```
SELECT     dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.Name AS 'Hostname', dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID, dbo.v_Collection.Name AS 'Collection Name', dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID, 
                      dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.IsDirect
FROM         dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership INNER JOIN
                      dbo.v_Collection ON dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM ON dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID
WHERE     (LOWER(dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.Name) = LOWER('Hostname'))
```

This script can be used with any SQL query on the SCCM database. All you need to do is update the SQL query in the script. i.e. the $memberQuery array (if you spread the query over a couple of lines like below, be sure to leave a space at the end of each line with exception to the last).

For example; If you'd like the script to show the clients collections with live advertisements assigned to them change the SQL query in the $memberQuery array to:-

```
$memberQuery = "SELECT dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.Name AS 'Hostname', dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID, dbo.v_Collection.Name AS 'Collection Name',dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID, dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.IsDirect, dbo.v_Advertisement.AdvertisementID, dbo.v_Advertisement.AdvertisementName "  
$memberQuery += "FROM dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership INNER JOIN dbo.v_Collection ON dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM ON dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID INNER JOIN dbo.v_Advertisement ON dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID = dbo.v_Advertisement.CollectionID "  
$memberQuery += "WHERE (LOWER(dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.Name) = LOWER('$srv'))"
```

and the $sObject variable to:-

```
$sObject = $enumColl | select Hostname, ResourceID, "Collection Name", CollectionID, IsDirect, AdvertisementID, AdvertisementName
```

Complete script to view client collections with live advisements (execution the same as before):-

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ( 
        [string] $hosts = "",
        [string] $sccmsrv = "",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=3)]
        [string] $path = ""
    )

$usage =  "USAGE: List-AdvertCollMembershipSCCM.ps1 -sccmsrv SCCMSERVER -hosts 'host1 host2 host3' -path 'c:\temp\Outfile.csv'"

if ($host -and $sccmsrv){

Write-Host ""       
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "SCCM Server: $sccmsrv"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Looking at hosts: $hosts"


  #### Function for executing a SQL query with integrated authentication  
  function execSQLQuery ([string]$fSQLServer, [string]$db, [string]$query){  
    $objConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection  
    $objConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $fSQLServer; Database = $db; trusted_connection=true;"  
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $query, $objConnection  
    trap {Write-Host -ForegroundColor 'red' "($sqlsrv/$db not accessible)";continue}   
    $SqlCmd.Connection.Open()  

    if ($SqlCmd.Connection.State -ine 'Open') {  
       $SqlCmd.Connection.Close()  
       return  
    }  
    $dr = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()  

    #get the data  
    $dt = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"  
    $dt.Load($dr)  
    $SqlCmd.Connection.Close()  
    $dr.Close()  
    $dr.Dispose()  
    $objConnection.Close()  
    return $dt  
  }  

  # read the SCCM site name of the SCCM site server  
  $site = (gwmi -ComputerName $sccmsrv -Namespace root\sms -Class SMS_ProviderLocation).sitecode  

  # enumerating SQL server name for the given SCCM site server  
  $sccmCompquery = gwmi -q "Select distinct SiteSystem, Role, SiteCode FROM SMS_SiteSystemSummarizer where role = 'SMS SQL Server' and siteCode = '$site' ORDER BY SiteCode" -namespace "root\sms\site_$site" -ComputerName $sccmsrv  
  [string]$tmpstr = [regex]::Match($sccmCompquery.sitesystem, "\\\\\w+\\$")  
  $sccmSQLServer = $tmpstr.replace("\", "")  
  $objColl = @()  

  #### Collate the host list.  
  $hostlist = @($Input)  
  if ($hosts) {  
    if($hosts -imatch " "){  
       $hostsArr = @($hosts.split(" "))
       $hostlist += $hostsArr  
    }  
    else{  
       $hostlist += $hosts  
    }  
  }  

  # going through the list of hosts  
  foreach($srv in $hostlist){  
    $memberQuery = "SELECT dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.Name AS 'Hostname', dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID, dbo.v_Collection.Name AS 'Collection Name',dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID, dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.IsDirect, dbo.v_Advertisement.AdvertisementID, dbo.v_Advertisement.AdvertisementName "  
    $memberQuery += "FROM dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership INNER JOIN dbo.v_Collection ON dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.CollectionID = dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID INNER JOIN dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM ON dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.ResourceID = dbo.v_GS_SYSTEM.ResourceID INNER JOIN dbo.v_Advertisement ON dbo.v_Collection.CollectionID = dbo.v_Advertisement.CollectionID "  
    $memberQuery += "WHERE (LOWER(dbo.v_FullCollectionMembership.Name) = LOWER('$srv'))"  

    # running sql query to enumerate list of collections the computer is member of  
    $membership = execSQLQuery $sccmSQLServer "SMS_$site" $memberQuery  

    # if we have a result, go through it and build an object collection with the computer name and the collection(s) it is member of  
    if($membership){  
       foreach($enumColl in $membership){

        $sObject = $enumColl | select Hostname, ResourceID, "Collection Name", CollectionID, IsDirect, AdvertisementID, AdvertisementName
        $objColl +=$sObject

       }  
    }  
  }
if ($objColl){
    if ($path){
        $objColl | ft -AutoSize
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Exporting to results to: $path"
        $objColl | Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
    }
    else{
    $objColl | ft -AutoSize
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Use the -path argument in the command line to export output to csv to display"
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "the header 'AdvertisementName'"
    Write-Host ""
    }
}
Else {
    foreach ($Hostname in $hostlist){
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The host $hostname is not a member of any collection with live advertisements"
    }
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Check you have entered the correct hostname and try again"
}
}
else {

    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $usage
}
```

Comment: I've since made a couple of changes to the script and removed the export to csv as a mandatory argument. It also got me thinking it would be good to have one that showed only the collections with live advertisements assigned to the client. I'll update the answer with both options

Comment: The last one you updated "Complete script to view client collections with live advisements (execution the same as before):-" just exports a blank .csv Do you know what could be happening ? Thanks

Comment: The scripts don't provide full error checking. i.e if the server name or hosts are incorrect the script will still run. Also with regards to the advertisement script, is the host you're running the script against a member of any collections with live advertisements? If not nothing would be exported. Try running it on a single host has an advert assigned. The collections will be in the output on the console also. With that said, I've updated both scripts in the answer to provide some (not all) level of error checking. i.e. If there is nothing in the $objColl array the script will notify you

Answer (score 1):

And if you connect to SCCM from station with only **SCCM Console** installed and every other SCCM cmdlets works, trying Get-WmiObject:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\sms\site_$SiteCode" ...
```

you will have an error:

```
“Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace …”
```

In this situation you should specify parameter ComputerName and point to server where SCCM is installed:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "SCCMserver" -Namespace "root\sms\site_$SiteCode" ...
```

Hope it helps, I waste few minutes by this.